# How to pass environment variables from docker-compose.yml to vite react project?

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, vite

I want to spesify some environment variables such as `API_URL` inside docker-compose.yml so I can change them by just restarting docker container. Otherwise I have to create docker container everytime I want to change the variables.

For example:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  frontend:
    container_name: "front"
    image: "front"
    ports:
      - 5005:80
    build:
      context: .
      # target: production
    environment:
      - VITE_API_URL=http://abcd.com
```

and somewhere inside Vite app:

```js
console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL);
```

I guess it doesn't work because docker's env and vite's env is different.

My idea is I can achieve similar result by creating a volume that contains .env file but I am  not sure if this is the best solution. Any ideas how to achieve this?

**Edit:** I found that it is impossible to change env var object after compiling the Vite project. I recommend using a DataBase for any variable data and request it at main.tsx level.

For API URLs, After trying different approaches I found out the best practice is using nginx reverse proxy.

**Explanation:**
When you using `fetch`, `axios` or any request handler method, you can send it without ip address like `fetch('/api/user')`. The application will direct it to it's own ip adress. Inside the docker container, you edit nginx config file like this:

```
location /api {
        proxy_pass http://abcd.com
    }
```

This will let nginx forward all requests those starts with `/api` to the entered URL endpoint. If you want to change the endpoint, you can just edit this configuration file and run `nginx -s reload` inside the docker. With this method, you can change the API endpoint without building the docker image.

Comment: when you define variables inside the `environment:` block, it exposes the key=value as the environment variables inside the docker container. so you should be able to read those environment variables from your application without any issues in the same way you read variables from `.env`. what is the problem you are having while reading the variable exposed from your compose file?

Comment: this is something with VITE if i recall correctly if you prefix an environment variable with `VITE_` it will be picked up and used by vite but will be declare without the prefix so in your case using `import.meta.env.API_URL` would work.

Comment: I just read the documentation and it contradicts what i said above, it did work in one of my projects though if i recall correctly.

Comment: reading it again it might be cause by some special chars have you tried wrapping it in `"` quotes or escaping using a backwards slash (\)?

Comment: Any update on this? i'm looking to pass the URL of a container created in the compose file as as env file

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it is not possible.

*During production, these env variables are statically replaced. It is therefore necessary to always reference them using the full static string. For example, dynamic key access like import.meta.env[key] will not work.*

https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html

Comment: did you find a way around this at all?

Comment: @WhatTheWhat see new answer

Comment: @WhatTheWhat, Edited the question. It might help you.

Comment: @Ceyco good!! also we can use docker env inside nginx.conf and set entrypoint in docker-compose file

Answer (score 1):

I found only one solution acceptable to me.

1. Docker compose will create enviroment-vars.js with the contents `window.VUE_DOMAIN_NAME = var_from_docker_env`

`command: ["sh", "-c", "echo window.VUE_DOMAIN_NAME='\"'$$VITE_URL'\' > public/enviroment-vars.js && echo $$VITE_URL && npm run dev" ]`

2. In index.html, add the path to this js file BEFORE all scripts.

`<script src="/enviroment-vars.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`.

3. In vite templates, use window.VUE_DOMAIN_NAME

Not the best solution, but it's better than creating a unique placeholder in templates and regexp it for the desired variable.